# Tracking event once in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am curious as to how users are exploring my app.  I only want to track an event the first time it happens.  For example, the first time a user beats level 1 I want to send an event.

Is there a way to easily send an event once with Google Analytics, or do I need to use `SharedPreferences` and manually track if I have sent an event before? (this is what I currently do)

I am unsure what keywords to search for this so links and tips are appreciated!

Comment: All events for each session will be logged to GA when they occur. If you want to see when an event has happened at all, then you can set up an event goal, as they are only logged once per session.